# Pug - retrieving keys from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, pug

I'm trying to create a single page website using Pug's templating engine and JSON as a database. Ultimately I'd like to store my different "pages" in the JSON file, and then render that JSON using different variables/mixins in my Pug template, but I keep receiving the errors, `cannot read property "company" of undefined`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my Gulp task to build my Pug files, and pipe the JSON into the template:

```
// build the Pug files into HTML
gulp.task('build-pug', function buildHTML(){
  var dataFile = 'source/javascript/pages.json';
  return gulp.src('source/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(data(function(file){
      return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(dataFile));
    }))
    .pipe(pug({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});
```

This is my `pages.json` file:

```
{
    "pages": [
        {
            "year": "2016",
            "company": "Abacus",
            "home": "./assets/images/2016/home/abacus.png",
            "home-url": "http://abacus.com",
            "login": "./assets/images/2016/login/abacus.png",
            "login-url": "http://abacus.com/login",
            "pricing": "./assets/images/2016/pricing/abacus.png",
            "pricing-url": "http://abacus.com/pricing"
        },
        {
            "year": "2016",
            "company": "Alfred",
            "home": "./assets/images/2016/home/alfred.png",
            "home-url": "http://alfred.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is in my `index.pug` file where I'm trying to call keys from my JSON:

```
section.pricing
    h1 Pricing Pages
    div.content.pricing

        each page in pages
            p= page.pages.company
```

Comment: No such thing as a JSON object. JSON is data-interchange format, i.e. a well-formed *string*.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I'm just learning development and referring to it as the W3C does. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: W3C is a *terrible* resource, that page being a case in point. Use MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Yeah, I use / read that quite a bit. From MDN: 

"We've implied above that a JSON object is basically a JavaScript object, and this is mostly right. You can include the same basic data types inside JSON as you can in a standard JavaScript object — strings, numbers, arrays, booleans, and other object literals. This allows you to construct a data hierarchy, like so ... "

"The following algorithm is an imitation of the native JSON object ... "

Should I not be reading MDN either?

Comment: Not sure which MDN page you got that from but here's one with a good treatment of the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about replacing your last line in index.pug with

`p= page.company`

Comment: Gosh, thanks so much! That's exactly what I was looking for.